# Java, reflection convert field into JAXBElement

Tags: soap, reflection, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to perform logging of SOAPMessage.
This object contains both wrapper classes and JAXBElements, I am doing something like this

```
@Before("soapRequest()")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

    Object[] signatureArgs = joinPoint.getArgs();
    System.out.println("\n\n\n");
    for (Object signatureArg : signatureArgs) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            Field[] aClassFields = signatureArg.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            sb.append(signatureArg.getClass().getSimpleName() + " [ ");
            for (Field f : aClassFields) {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                String fName = f.getName();

                String value = "";
                if(f.get(signatureArg) instanceof JAXBElement) {
                    log.info("is instance of");
                    JAXBElement val = (JAXBElement) f.get(signatureArg);
                    log.info(val.toString());
                    value = val.getValue().toString();
                } else {
                    value = f.get(signatureArg).toString();
                }

                sb.append("(" + f.getType() + ") " + fName + " = " + value + ", ");
            }
            sb.append("]");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

However this line throws NPE:

```
if(f.get(signatureArg) instanceof JAXBElement) {
                        log.info("is instance of");
                        JAXBElement val = (JAXBElement) f.get(signatureArg);
                        log.info(val.toString());
                        value = val.getValue().toString();
                    }
```

How Can I check if the field is instance of JAXBElement and extract value from it?

Comment: Mateusz, you have been an SO member for some years and have considerable reputation of 500+ points. I think you should know what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and how to write questions that result in good answers. Help your helpers to help you by providing more than just snippets. Nobody can compile and run your code. Not even the aspect is complete, missing a pointcut. I believe it would be helpful to add it and also a sample class producing values the aspect ought to intercept. Then the problem would be reproducible.

Comment: One more thought: You are quite fixated on **how** you want to do something technically, but there is not enough information for anyone to understand **what** you want to achieve and **why**. This is called the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898). Maybe some context information would be helpful, inspiring others and yourself to think about alternative solutions too. This one looks very contrived and potentially slow due to heavy usage of reflection. Is this a debugging/tracing aspect only or do you use it in a production environment? AOP does not replace a debugger.

Comment: You also didn't provide a stack trace. You said: "this line throws NPE" but then quote 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think your NPE occurs in the `then` block at this line of code:

```java
value = f.get(signatureArg).toString();
```

It happens if the field value is `null` because on `null` you cannot call `toString()`. By the way, this should happen for any `null` field, not just for `JAXBElement`. You do not need `toString()`, you can just remove it because when you print any object, it will automatically use its `toString()` representation where applicable.

In my opinion your code is also more complicated than necessary and with some restructuring and renaming variables the `then` block is no longer necessary at all. Here is my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in plain Java + AspectJ (no Spring) for you:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

public class Container {
  private String name;
  private JAXBElement jaxbElement;

  public Container(String name, JAXBElement jaxbElement) {
    this.name = name;
    this.jaxbElement = jaxbElement;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Application {
  public void doSomething(int number, String text, Container myContainer) {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application();
    application.doSomething(11, "foo", new Container("bar", new JAXBElement(new QName("local"), String.class, "dummy")));
    application.doSomething(11, "foo", new Container("bar", null));
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Pointcut("execution(* doSomething(..))")
  private void soapRequest() {}

  @Before("soapRequest()")
  public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);

    for (Object methodArg : joinPoint.getArgs()) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      try {
        sb.append(methodArg.getClass().getSimpleName() + " [ ");
        for (Field field : methodArg.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
          field.setAccessible(true);
          String fieldName = field.getName();
          Object value = field.get(methodArg);
          if (value instanceof JAXBElement) {
            System.out.println("  -> is instance of");
            JAXBElement jaxbElement = (JAXBElement) value;
            System.out.println("  -> " + jaxbElement);
            value = jaxbElement.getValue();
          }
          // Un-comment this in order to see the NPE
          //else {
          //  value = field.get(methodArg).toString();
          //}
          sb.append("(" + field.getType() + ") " + fieldName + " = " + value + ", ");
        }
        sb.append("]");
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println("  " + sb);
    }
  }
}
```

The console log looks like this:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething(int, String, Container))
  Integer [ (int) MIN_VALUE = -2147483648, (int) MAX_VALUE = 2147483647, (class java.lang.Class) TYPE = int, (class [C) digits = [C@8efb846, (class [C) DigitTens = [C@2a84aee7, (class [C) DigitOnes = [C@a09ee92, (class [I) sizeTable = [I@30f39991, (int) value = 11, (int) SIZE = 32, (int) BYTES = 4, (long) serialVersionUID = 1360826667806852920, ]
  String [ (class [C) value = [C@4a574795, (int) hash = 0, (long) serialVersionUID = -6849794470754667710, (class [Ljava.io.ObjectStreamField;) serialPersistentFields = [Ljava.io.ObjectStreamField;@f6f4d33, (interface java.util.Comparator) CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER = java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator@23fc625e, ]
  -> is instance of
  -> javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement@4f023edb
  Container [ (class java.lang.String) name = bar, (class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement) jaxbElement = dummy, ]
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething(int, String, Container))
  Integer [ (int) MIN_VALUE = -2147483648, (int) MAX_VALUE = 2147483647, (class java.lang.Class) TYPE = int, (class [C) digits = [C@8efb846, (class [C) DigitTens = [C@2a84aee7, (class [C) DigitOnes = [C@a09ee92, (class [I) sizeTable = [I@30f39991, (int) value = 11, (int) SIZE = 32, (int) BYTES = 4, (long) serialVersionUID = 1360826667806852920, ]
  String [ (class [C) value = [C@4a574795, (int) hash = 0, (long) serialVersionUID = -6849794470754667710, (class [Ljava.io.ObjectStreamField;) serialPersistentFields = [Ljava.io.ObjectStreamField;@f6f4d33, (interface java.util.Comparator) CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER = java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator@23fc625e, ]
  Container [ (class java.lang.String) name = bar, (class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement) jaxbElement = null, ]
```

See? Your error has gone. Un-comment the `else` block in order to see it re-appear, then remove the `.toString()` from the line and it goes away again. Maybe it helps you understand your error better.

By the way, I think the log output looks kinda ugly. Did you also notice that you print static fields too? You should probably filter them out. But I did not want to change more of your code because I still want you to recognise it.

---

The short version of your aspect without the additional debug logging for `JAXBElement` and without `try - catch` but a declared exception instead would be:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Pointcut("execution(* doSomething(..))")
  private void soapRequest() {}

  @Before("soapRequest()")
  public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
    for (Object methodArg : joinPoint.getArgs()) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(methodArg.getClass().getSimpleName() + " [ ");
      for (Field field : methodArg.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        Object value = field.get(methodArg);
        if (value instanceof JAXBElement)
          value = ((JAXBElement) value).getValue();
        sb.append("(" + field.getType() + ") " + fieldName + " = " + value + ", ");
      }
      sb.append("]");
      System.out.println("  " + sb);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kriegaex. Actually it happened what you said about toString() method. Some of SOAP vields were empty and when calling toString() on them I got NPE.